# Can I say only when $g(t)=0$ the above condition holds? Why?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\theta g(t) n t^{n-1} \theta^{-n} dt =0, 0<t<\theta$$

Can I say only when $g(t)=0$ the above condition holds **for all $\theta$?** Why?

I can see $n$ and $\theta^{-n}$ above are constants (n is finite and fixed, but positive integer). So I can throw away them. Then the integral becomes
$$\int_0^\theta g(t)  t^{n-1}  dt =0$$

Comment: Are you taking a limit w.r.t. $n$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry, I don't know what do you mean.

Comment: w.r.t. means "with respect to". Is there a $$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$ in your original problem?

Comment: @NinadMunshi n is finite and fixed, but positive integer.

Comment: I see your edited comment now. The reason I brought it up is because if $n\to\infty$, then you can't just throw it away, you would have had a L'Hopital limit that you would have had to consider.

Comment: If it holds for all $\theta$ the answer is yes. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus as the deleted answer suggested.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I can't see your deleted answer. Can you send it again?

Comment: It's not my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus (take the derivative of both sides with respect to $\theta$).

$g(\theta)\theta^{n-1}=0$

Comment: I think you mean take the derivative of both sides with respect to $\theta$.